# for NaN in dataframe i should pass value 0.00(percentage format) in excel not 0. using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

input:

```
         del       wait
0     458.333333    NaN
1     NaN           546.153846
```

using: `df['wait']=df['wait'].mul(100).div(df['del'], axis=0).round(2).fillna(0)`

output in excel should be:

```
del          wait
458.333333    0.00
0.00          546.153846
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe `df = df.fillna('0.00')` will already suffice the requirement?